# How can I use [Author Year] like new ACM Style?

Tags: bibtex, citing, acm

I'm use the TeX ACM Style in my thesis:

```
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{Anderson_EQM}
```

And cite references using `\cite{}`, but it's different of the new ACM style:

**[Number]** instead **[Author Year]**

How can I use [Author Year] like ACM Style?

Thanks

---

Obs.: In ACM examples, the cite and reference styles are:

> TYPICAL REFERENCES IN NEW ACM REFERENCE FORMAT
>
> A paginated journal article [Abril and Plant 2007], an enumerated
>   journal article [Cohen et al. 2007], a reference to an entire issue
>   [Cohen 1996], a monograph (whole book) [Kosiur 2001], a
>   monograph/whole book in a series (see 2a in spec. document) [Harel
>   1979], a divisible-book such as an anthology or...

REFERENCES

> Rafal Ablamowicz and Bertfried Fauser. 2007. CLIFFORD: a Maple 11 Package for Clifford Algebra Computations, version 11. (2007). Retrieved February 28, 2008 from http://math.tntech.edu/rafal/cliff11/index.html
>
> Patricia S. Abril and Robert Plant. 2007. The patent holder’s dilemma: Buy, sell, or troll? Commun. ACM 50, 1 (Jan. 2007), 36–44. DOI:http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1188913.1188915

Comment: Which document class do you use? And, is using the `natbib` citation-managent package an option for you?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}, and I'm not using natbib.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need to load the `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals` style to get citations and references in the form described in the excerpts you've posted. I.e., issue the command

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
```

instead of `\bibliographystyle{acm}`. If you don't already have this style file, go to the [ACM LaTeX Style Guide](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) webpage and download and unpack any one of the three zip files for authors (v2-acmsmall.zip, v2-acmlarge.zip, v2-acmtog.zip), and then copy the `.bst` file to the directory that contains your TeX file(s).

To get authoryear-style citations, you should also load the `natbib` package.

---

Addendum Feb. 2017: The ACM LaTeX style guide webpage appear to have migrated to https://www.acm.org/publications/acm-latex-style-guide-3jan2017.

---

Addendum Apr. 2021: The ACM LaTeX style guide webpage has migrated yet again. It is currently available at [ACM Primary Article Templates AND Publication Workflow](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/word-template-workflow). Note that there are separate templates, depending on whether your computer uses MacOS or Windows. (I have no idea what users of Linux, etc, might want to do.) The ACM's template files are now also available in an [Overleaf depository](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/acm-official#.WOuOk2e1taQ).

Comment: Thanks. I had used this style, however I need use acm.cls. and I get some errors :-(

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. Are you also experiencing problems if you use one of the `.cls` class files provided in the three `.zip` files I mention in my answer?

Comment: Yes. I used acmlarge.cls.

Comment: I would just like to format the citations and references, and not whole document.

Comment: @Anderson - I'm afraid I'm not sure what your main issue is. Please be a bit more specific than saying that "I get some errors". Is something preventing you from using the `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals` bib style along with a document class such as `article` or `report`? When switching from one bib style to another, be sure to remember to wipe out the `.aux` and other auxilliary files before recompiling.

Comment: The template seems to have moved again, and the file "ACM-Reference-Format-Journals.bst" doesn't seem to exist. This answer looks promising, but should be updated.

Comment: @imallett - Thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. I've edited my answer to provide a second addendum, to provide links to two locations. Hopefully, these locations will be valid for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `apalike` instead of `acm`.

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

This will give you citations of the form

> [author, year]

Comment: Thanks. But, in APALike references are:

[Ablamowicz, 2007] Ablamowicz R. 2007. CLIFFORD: a Maple ...
[Abril and Plant, 2007] Abril P. S. and Plant R. 2007. The patent ...

And ACM are:

Rafal Ablamowicz and Bertfried Fauser. 2007. CLIFFORD: a Maple ...
Patricia S. Abril and Robert Plant. 2007. The patent ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\citestyle{authoryear}` before `\begin{document}` in the current ACM Template.

It is written in the preamble:

```
%% The majority of ACM publications use numbered citations and
%% references.  The command \citestyle{authoryear} switches to the
%% "author year" style.
%%
%% If you are preparing content for an event
%% sponsored by ACM SIGGRAPH, you must use the "author year" style of
%% citations and references.
%% Uncommenting
%% the next command will enable that style.
%% \citestyle{acmauthoryear}
```

It is easy to overlook. I asked the chairs about this.